# escape not working, xev detects weird event

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, i3

I've encountered a strange issue in my EndeavourOS-i3wm system. The escape key is not functioning at all. I haven't reconfigured any keyboard settings or messed with xkbmap. This problem occurred when I attempted to open a file in Doom Emacs. It's possible that I pressed multiple keys simultaneously, but I'm not entirely sure.

Super+ESC does the action bound to it, but nothing happens after ESC inside most software. Curiosly, it also seems to be application-specific: ESC does kill the rofi menu, but it still does nothing inside Rstudio, VIM, EMACS, firefox...

If I run xev, then press the escape key, I get

```
FocusOut event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  111 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

It randomly starts to work spontaneously, when I get this:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x798, subw 0x0, time 983421, (-228,520), root:(1057,532),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x798, subw 0x0, time 983529, (-228,520), root:(1057,532),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False
```

after `sudo showkey -> ESC`, I get

```
keycode   1 press
keycode   1 release
```

Running `setxkbmap` does nothing.
`etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf`:

```
# Read and parsed by systemd-localed. It's probably wise not to edit this file
# manually too freely.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "br"
EndSection
```

Running `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` gets me this:

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     br
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+br+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+br+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

If I restore to a previous timeshift snapshot everything is fine, and this happens across different keyboards, it is driving me crazy.

Is it possible that the keymap got screwed in such a specific way, as to brake only the ESC key?

** UPDATE **

After reading @dirkt's answer, I found out which software was stealing the ESC key. I had the fromScratch software open in a hidden scratchpad i3wm buffer. It is awesome and works as a hacky solution to have a pop-up floating fromScratch app. This was stealing ESCAPE. Killing it solves the problem.

Comment: what's the output of `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` in terminal?

Comment: @Andra, I posted the required info. Is this helpful?

Comment: it doesn't show any mapping different from default for your chosen layout. With "across different keyboards" you mean physical keyboards?

Comment: yes, Andra, I just wanted to say I am sure this is not a keyboard hardware issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer (and this has been asked before at least once, either here or on superuser):

The `FocusOut` and `FocusIn` events mean that there is some other application running that is stealing the <kbd>ESC</kbd> keypress.

Changing your keyboard layout won't affect this at all.

Typically this is used by "language" extensions that allow to type foreign characters using key combinations on existing keyboard layouts. But in principle it can be anything, even your window manager (which I am not familiar with).

So you need to figure out which application is running that is stealing the events. `xlsclients` or `ps` may help. Systematically debug by killing or uninstalling apps. Only you can do this, there is not enough information in the question to find this out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarifications. I suspect it may have something to do with DOOM EMACS, and maybe the R language server "ESS", as the problem is somewhat associated with starting and emacs client. I will look into that in the future (as I said, it comes and goes, and I am not facing that problem at this moment).

Comment: Would you mind sharing these other similar questions and answers?

Comment: nevermind, I found these:
https://superuser.com/questions/1331249/linux-what-is-stealing-my-keypress-combination
https://superuser.com/questions/1358962/i3-how-to-use-media-keys-that-show-up-on-separate-input-device/1358992#1358992
https://superuser.com/questions/931873/o-and-i-appearing-on-iterm2-when-focus-lost/931901#931901